# Is it safe to store userId in Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, redux, state

I have a React app with a shopping cart that has state managed by Redux.

- The user first logs in using OAuth 2.0 with Google.
- When the user puts items in their cart, a Redux action puts the item info and their user id into the 'cart' state.
- The checkout page has a function that filters through the Redux 'cart' state and returns/displays only the items with a userId property that matches the current logged in userId.

Obviously the cart state object with userIds is then public. Is this a big security risk? Or is the userId fine to have in state that can be seen by the public?

Comment: The question you should be asking to yourself is : how valuable the `userId` is? If I happen to get access to the `userId`, can I do something obnoxious?

Comment: @raksozorw, it depends on you. If your application works only in client's network then it may be okay but if it is available throughout the internet then it's not.